# Shiny erro na hora de gerar o HTML

Tags: r, shiny

Estou tentando "criar uma calculadora de probabilidades para as distribuições Normal e Binomial, porem esta dando algum erro na hora de gera o HTML.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].Segue os códigos abaixo.

*PS:seria possível trocar o mi e sigma por letras gregas?*

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(
titlePanel("Calculadora"),  
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(inputId="dist",
    label="Escolha sua distribuição:",
    choices=c("Binomial"="bin","Normal"="normal"),selected = "bin"),
    sliderInput(inputId="x",label="Escolha o valor de X:",
     min=0,max=50,step = 1,value = 10),
     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dist=='bin'",
    sliderInput(inputId = "n",label = "Escolha o valor de N:",
     min=0,max=50,step=1,value=25),
    sliderInput(inputId ="p",label="Escolha o valor de P",
      min=0,max = 1,value=0.5)),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dist=='normal'",
    sliderInput(inputId = "s",label = "Escolha o valor de sigma",
      min=0,max=50,step=1,value=25),
    sliderInput(inputId ="m",label="Escolha o valor de mi",
     min=0,max=50,step=1,value=25))
    ),
    mainPanel(textOutput("text_calc"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text_calc<-renderPrint({
    if (input$dist=="bin"){
      N<-input$n
      P<-input$p
      k<-input$x
      D<-pbinom(k,N,P)
      paste("Probabilidade pedida:", D)
    }
    if (input$dist=="normal"){
      S<-input$s
      M<-input$m
      k<-input$x
      D<-pnorm(k,M,S)
      paste("Probabilidade pedida:", D)
    }
  }
)

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema estava nos dois `if` encadeados. Tirei um deles e substituí por um `else`. Tá tudo bem agora.

Se for do teu interesse expandir esta calculadora para mais distribuições, é só ir colocando mais `else` após o segundo.

As letras gregas podem ser colocadas através da função `withMathJax()`, que carrega a biblioteca MathJax, responsável pela notação matemática baseada em LaTeX. Veja a segunda linha do código do `ui` para ver como carreguei a biblioteca. Depois veja os `sliderInput` correspondentes a sigma e mi para ver como eu escrevi eles com a letra grega correspondente.

Pesquise sobre LaTeX para descobrir como fazer outras letras gregas e expressões matemáticas mais complexas, como integrais, derivadas parciais e, bem, qualquer outra coisa imaginável.

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage( titlePanel("Calculadora"),
           withMathJax(),
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput(inputId="dist",
                           label="Escolha sua distribuição:",
                           choices=c("Binomial"="bin","Normal"="normal"),selected = "bin"),
               sliderInput(inputId="x",label="Escolha o valor de X:",
                           min=0,max=50,step = 1,value = 10),
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dist=='bin'",
                                sliderInput(inputId = "n",label = "Escolha o valor de N:",
                                            min=0,max=50,step=1,value=25),
                                sliderInput(inputId ="p",label="Escolha o valor de P",
                                            min=0,max = 1,value=0.5)),
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dist=='normal'",
                                sliderInput(inputId = "s",label = "Escolha o valor de \\(\\sigma\\)",
                                            min=0,max=50,step=1,value=25),
                                sliderInput(inputId ="m",label="Escolha o valor de \\(\\mu\\)",
                                            min=0,max=50,step=1,value=25))
             ),
             mainPanel(textOutput("text_calc"))
           ) )

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$text_calc<-renderPrint({ 
    if (input$dist=="bin"){ 
      N<-input$n 
      P<-input$p 
      k<-input$x 
      D<-pbinom(k,N,P) 
      paste("Probabilidade pedida:", D) 
      } else { 
        S<-input$s 
        M<-input$m 
        k<-input$x 
        D<-pnorm(k,M,S) 
        paste("Probabilidade pedida:", D) } 
  }
)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Marcus :)

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.